# Input tag won't work with JQuery Ajax properly

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I made a code where when the client types something in the input, it will send the data to a jsp file to evaluate, and if the data equals "James", it will say "Hello James". The problem is that the input tag won't display your input, and only takes 1 input

```
     jQuery w/ input
<fieldset>
<form style="padding:15px;">
<label for=name>Enter Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
</form>
</fieldset>

<div id="result"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("input").keypress(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var send = {
          name: name 
        };

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "process2.jsp",
          data: send,
          success: function(data) {
            $("#result").html(data);
          }
        })
      });
    });


</script>
   -----------------------

    JSP FILE:
   <%

    String name = request.getParameter("name");

    if(name.equals("James")){
out.println("Hello James");
     } else {
out.println("Hello User");
    }

    %>
```

Comment: What does `input tag won't display your input, and only takes 1 input..` this means ? can you elaborate it more ? try to use `keyup` instead of `keypress` event.

Comment: It means the input text box wont display more than 1 characters. I'll also make sure to use more keyups

Comment: Try to change `$("input").keypress(function(event) ` to `$("input").keyup(function(event) ` and check if it works .

Comment: yea it's working well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code ist that you are assigning the name variable incorrectly. Instead of writing.

```
        var name = $("#name").val();
```

You should write

```
        var name = event.target.value;
```

Otherwise you are assigning the same value over and over again with every key press, making it impossible to type more than a single character.

Comment: Also you might want to consider removing event.preventDefault() from your code. Why do you have it in there anyway?

Comment: The prevent default is from the previous version. But anyways thxs for the help

Comment: Did my answer fix the cause of your problem? If it did, please be so kind and mark it as the accepted answer. Otherwise let me know!

Comment: yea I just did. new to stackoverflow so didnt know such thing existed